# Change Powerpoint Link to Different Folder

Tags: excel, powerpoint, vba

I want to transfer the link in the graphs of a PowerPoint presentation to another folder. Found some code but it only selects specific file to change link to, not folders, which I can't use because my PowerPoint is link to two different Excel files (in the same folder).

```
Sub M1()
Dim sld As Slide
Dim sh As Shape
Dim strNms As String
Dim intI As Integer
Dim strNewPath
Dim ExcelFile
Dim exl As Object
Set exl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Open a dialog box to promt for the new source file.
ExcelFile = exl.Application.GetOpenFilename(, , "Select Excel File")
For Each sld In ActivePresentation.aSlides
    For Each sh In sld.Shapes
        If sh.Type = msoLinkedOLEObject Then
            With sh.LinkFormat
                strNms = .SourceFullName
                intI = InStr(1, strNms, "!")
                strNewPath = ExcelFile & Mid(strNms, intI, Len(strNms) - intI + 1)
                .SourceFullName = strNewPath
            End With
        End If
    Next sh
Next sld
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the code here:

Batch Search and Replace for Hyperlinks, OLE links, movie links and sound links
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00773_Batch_Search_and_Replace_for_Hyperlinks-_OLE_links-_movie_links_and_sound_links.htm

It'll let you, for example, replace the path to the linked file (ie, different folder name) but not change the name of the linked file.

Important:  You must have the file to be relinked in the folder you're trying to relink TO before running the code.  If you change a link to point to a file that's not there, PPT will just smile at you and say "OK" but it won't change anything.